# reference to a \section*{}

Tags: sectioning, ref

I need to answer my assignment in latex with a

```
Assignment 1a 
Assignment 1b
Assignment 1c
Assignment 2a
Assignment 2b
```

I have tried to use the \section*{}, but referencing then doesn't work. Is there another way of being able to have a section and subsection with numbers and letters as shown above?

Comment: Thank you :-) Could you give an example? Would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it, with no package just using `\section` and an `assignment` environment.  Since this abuses the `\section` command, it's not usable within a document that also requires regular sections, but the approach could be adapted use `\subsection` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{assignment}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Assignment~\arabic{assignment}\alph{section}}
\newenvironment{assignment}{\refstepcounter{assignment}}{\setcounter{section}{0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{assignment}
\section{First sub assignment}
\section{Second sub assignment}
\section{Third sub assignment}
\end{assignment}
\begin{assignment}
\section{First sub assignment}
\section{Second sub assignment}
\end{assignment}
\end{document}
```